# Autolayout labels with UIView and Labels inside UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am new to the autolayout thing, was trying to design the given screen for `Compact Width|Regular Height` via Storyboard. It seems Very simple cause there is none dynamic fields. I was following apple documentation, and setting constraints for each UIView. Its working fine if there would be no `View(shown in purple color)`. But there is some requirement(have to hide the View based on star rating), thats why added this UIView containing dispatch details, complaint category, screenshot etc. e.g- For `Invoice Number I set Top Space,Leading Space, Trailing Space` and  for the `label(shown in green color) Top Space, Leading Space, Trailing Space` so that height of invoice Number wouldn't be ambiguous rep, Repeated same for all Views. UIView(purple) constraints are `Trailing Space to:SuperView, Bottom space to:SuperView, Bottom space to:Remarks Equals:15, Top Space Equals to:StarRating Equals:8`. After that I have added constraints for the fields inside the purple View same as the other Views like `Invoice Number`. But not getting the desired result for different screen size. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What result are you getting, and what are you expecting?

Comment: expecting same as shown in the screenshot, after adding all the constraints the UIView(purple) gets disappeared. It works fine till `Star Rating`.

Comment: What is your deployment target? iOS 9? iOS 8?

Comment: iOS 8 and above, can't use StackView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `UITableView` to lay out this screen. You can use a static content table view, laid out entirely in the storyboard. Make the purple part its own section. In your `UITableViewController` subclass, you don't need to implement most data source / delegate methods (because you're using static content). Just override `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` to return 0 for the optional section if you don't want to show it, and use `-[UITableView reloadSections:withRowAnimation;]` to update the table view. Here's my test code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *topMarginCell;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *star1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *star2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *star3;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *star4;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *star5;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<UIButton *> *starButtons;

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger rating;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.starButtons = @[ self.star1, self.star2, self.star3, self.star4, self.star5 ];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = self.topMarginCell.backgroundColor;
}

- (void)reloadDispatchSection {
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}

- (IBAction)starButtonWasTapped:(UIButton *)button {
    NSInteger buttonIndex = [self.starButtons indexOfObject:button];
    if (buttonIndex == NSNotFound) { return; }
    self.rating = buttonIndex + 1;

    [self.starButtons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        [obj setTitle:(idx <= buttonIndex ? @"★" : @"☆") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }];

    [self reloadDispatchSection];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 1 && (self.rating == 0 || self.rating >= 4)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return [super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
    }
}

@end
```

Result:

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks for your effort rob, I'll test it and let you know.

Comment: One More thing can u explain to me how to write that star(*) as string, right now I am using IBDesignable to make that star in my UIView. But rendering and handling the click on it get lots of code, your code looks minimal and clean.

Comment: You can copy it from my answer and paste it into your code. I “typed” it by opening the Emoji & Symbols panel from the Edit menu in Xcode, then searching for “star”.

Comment: All rob at S/O are superstar :)