# Is there an easy way to implement a star rating in iOS as there is in android

Tags: ios, objective-c, ratingbar

I worked on android, and there I used a rating bar to show star ratings.
But in iOS I can't find the same functionality. Is there some easy way to do this in iOS as there is in android?

Is there any core functionality of iOS, some kind of view that I can use?

Comment: You can use it with these library: 
https://github.com/erndev/EDStarRating and
https://github.com/hsousa/HCSStarRatingView

Comment: i saw some of the libraries, what i want to know is that, Is there any core functionality for doing the same.

Comment: No, there are not. But you can do it yourself. Here is the tutorial for doing that: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-in-ios-5-a-5-star-rating-view

Comment: There are many way to do that. If you want to do it yourself, without using library, contact my email.

Answer (score 2):

The iOS SDK does not include anything comparable to Android's `RatingBar` as of iOS 9.2.

I recently posted an answer that includes a five-star ratings bar, implemented using five buttons. You can see the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34641167/77567).